# Break Hyper Link not working

Tags: hyperref

Below is my code,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdfpagemode=none,%
colorlinks,%
citecolor=blue,%
filecolor=blue,%
linkcolor=blue,%
urlcolor=blue
}
\begin{document}

This a Sample, This a Sample, This a Sample, This a Sample, This i\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF0000000}{\textbf{32}, 396 (1964)}

\end{document}
```

I am using dvi2ps and ps2pdf to create PDF output, my problem is hyperlink not working when the link text is broken, please guide me,

As shown in the below image, first line link doesn't show the link as second line of text
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Thanks for the help

Below code is working fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{url}
\hypersetup{
pdfpagemode=none,%
colorlinks,%
citecolor=blue,%
filecolor=blue,%
linkcolor=blue,%
urlcolor=blue
}

\begin{document}

If you have any questions, at \burlalt{www.goooooggggggle.comssss}{32, 396, (1964)}

If you have any questions, at have any questions, at have have \burlalt{www.goooooggggggle.comssss}{32, 396, (1964)}

\end{document}
```

But now my minor issue is i can't able to use \textbf{} in

\burlalt{www.goooooggggggle.comssss}{\textbf{32}, 396, (1964)}

actually i am new to latex, so kindly guide me,

Answer (score 4):

From `hyperref`'s [`README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf):

> ### Wrapped/broken link support
>
> Only few drivers support automatically wrapped/broken links,   e.g. pdftex, dvipdfm, hypertex. Other drivers
>   lack this   feature, e.g. dvips, dvipsone.
>
> Workarounds:
>
> - For long section or caption titles in the table of contents
>     or list of figures/tables option `linktocpage` can be used.
>     Then the page number will be a link, and the overlong section
>     title is not forced into an one line link with overvull `\hbox`
>     warning.
> - `\url`s are caught by package `breakurl`.
> - The option `breaklinks` is intended for internal use. But it
>     can be used to force link wrapping, e.g. when printing a
>     document. However, when such a document is converted to PDF
>     and viewed with a PDF viewer, the active link area will be
>     misplaced.
>       Another limitation: some penalties are "optimized" by TeX,
>     thus there are missing break points, especially within
>     `\url`. (See thread `hyperref.sty`, `breaklinks` and `url.sty` 3.2"
>     in comp.text.tex 2005-09).

Comment: You may want to state explicitly what the OP should do to address his/her issue: Don't use the `breaklinks` option, load the `breakurl` package instead. Would you agree?

Comment: @Mico: Or `pdflatex` or ... and I am back, where I have started with a long list of possibilities.

Comment: So, this is not possible without using pdflatex, isn't it?? Is it possible to use breakurl in dvi->ps and ps->pdf option

Comment: @user52124: First sentence of [`breakurl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breakurl)'s [`README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/breakurl/README): "The breakurl is an extension to hyperref package that allows line-breakable `\url`-like links when compiling via latex + dvips + ps2pdf"."

Comment: Is it possible to use \textbf inside \burlalt tag

Comment: @user52124: No, also the second arguemnt of `\burlalt` is treated as URL and not as general LaTeX markup.

Comment: @user52124: This [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179879/16967) provides a solution via package `soul`.