# \textbf{} not working inside Breakurl \burlalt

Tags: hyperref, urls

Below is my code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{url}
\hypersetup{
pdfpagemode=none,%
colorlinks,%
citecolor=blue,%
filecolor=blue,%
linkcolor=blue,%
urlcolor=blue
}

\begin{document}

If you have any questions, at \burlalt{www.goooooggggggle.comssss}{32, 396, (1964)}

If you have any questions, at \burlalt{www.goooooggggggle.comssss}{\textbf{32}, 396, (1964)}

If you have any questions, at have any questions, at have have \burlalt{www.goooooggggggle.comssss}{32, 396, (1964)}

L.~A.~Anchordoqui, H.~Goldberg, and G.~Steigman, Phys.
Lett. B
\burlalt{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2012.12.019}{718, 1162 (2013)}.


\end{document}
```

when i use \textbf{} inside \burlalt, it throws some error, is it possible to use those commands inside \burlalt, please guide me, i am new to latex

Comment: BTW, `UseNone` is the correct value for `pdfpagemode`. See also the `.log` file that lists the accepted values in the warning message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example defines macro `\breakhref`, which can be used similar to `\href`. The first argument is the URL as in the first argument of `\href`.

The second argument of `\href` can contain quite general LaTeX text. It is non-trivial to divide this text at hyphenation and breaking points to insert links for each part (syllables, spaces, ...) later. This is the domain of package [`soul`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul). It has an interface to define custom drivers, where only the handling of the different element types are defined.

Dividing a general LaTeX text string into atomic units (syllables, ...) is far from trivial. There are some restrictions to be respected.
Reading the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf) of package `soul` is therefore highly recommended, especially sections "2.1 Some things work ..." and "2.2 ... other don't".

**Remarks:**

- The implementation takes some effort to retain the flexibility of the interword spaces without leaving gaps in the link.
- Each atomic unit gets a `\vphantom{<complete text>}` to get a uniform height and depth of the link. For example, if links are underlined, the line should therefore be at the same vertical positions for the elements on the same line. Underlining means underlined links of the PDF annotation (via `hyperref` option `pdfborderstyle`). Since the DVI format does not retain the box dimensions, the underlining in `xdvi`'s is "ragged".
- Implicit hyphens, set by the hyphenation at the end of the line, are *not* part of the links due to limitations of `\discretionary`, which does not allow `\special` for the link feature
  inside its lists. This can also be considered as feature, because this hyphens does not originally belongs to the link text.

  Explicit hyphens are supported as links.
- This method increases the number of link annotations, because each part constitutes a new independent link.

Full example:

```
% latex/dvips/ps2pdf
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
  pdfpagemode=UseNone,
  colorlinks,
  allcolors=blue,
  % allbordercolors=blue,
  % pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1},
}

\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\breakhref}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\breakhref}{%
  \begingroup
  \hyper@normalise\breakhref@
}
\newcommand*{\breakhref@}[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \SOUL@setup
  \def\SOUL@everyspace##1{%
    ##1%
    \dimen@=\fontdimen2\font
    \advance\dimen@ by \fontdimen3\font
    \cleaders\hbox to \dimen@{%
      \hss
      \href{#1}{\ \vphantom{#2}}%
      \hss
    }\hskip\dimen@\relax
    \hspace{-\fontdimen3\font
        plus \fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen3\font}%
  }%
  \def\SOUL@everysyllable{%
    \href{#1}{\the\SOUL@syllable\vphantom{#2}}%
  }%
  \def\SOUL@everyhyphen{%
    \discretionary{-}{}{}%
  }%
  \def\SOUL@everyexhyphen##1{%
    \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
    \href{#1}{##1\vphantom{#2}}%
    \discretionary{}{}{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
    }%
  }%
  \SOUL@{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

If you have any questions, at
\breakhref{http://www.example.org/}{32, 396, (1964)}

If you have any questions, at
\breakhref{http://www.example.org/}{\textbf{32}, 396, (1964)}

\medskip

L.~A.~Anchordoqui and H.~Goldberg, Phys.
Lett. B
\breakhref{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2012.12.019}{%
  718, 1162 (2013)}.

\medskip

\breakhref{http://www.example.net}{%
  This little macro will hardly be good enough for linguists.
  Example-with-explicit-hyphens.}

\medskip

\parbox{1mm}{%
  \breakhref{http://www.example.net}%
  {This little macro is non-trivial.}
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result/colorlinks]

Variant with underlined links via

```
allbordercolors=blue,
pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1},
```

> [image: Result/underline]

In the third-last line the explicit hyphen in `non-` is linked, the implicit hyphen in the second-last line `triv-` is not. The partial overlap is due to a negative kerning between `v` and `-` that is not ignored by `soul`.

Not recommended are boxed links, because each element is boxed:

> [image: Result/boxes]

Comment: Thank you very much, this saved a lot of Headache, it works like charm

Answer (score 1):

`\burlalt` is meant for two urls not for one url and arbitrary text. Use `\href` instead:

```
 \href{www.goooooggggggle.comssss}{\textbf{32}, 396, (1964)}
```

Comment: The problem is i used \href and had breaking problem, so i shifted to \burlalt to counter that :-)

Comment: But you don't display an url but arbitrary text with spaces in it. There will no problem with hyphenation there. (btw: imho the breakurl documentation confused the two argument. It displays the first and not the second.)

Comment: Actually i want "32, 396 (1964)" as display and it is working fine, only thing is i need to make bold for 32

Comment: Did you try my code? Is there a problem with it?

Comment: @Fischer, I used that code \href already, problem with that is when we use DVI2ps and PS2PDF, the link won't be generated in PDF, for the broken link text, that's why i switched to \burlalt

Comment: `\href` works fine with dvips (naturally the first argument must be a valid url http://...). If it wouldn't work `\burlalt` wouldn't work either, as breakurl is based on hyperref.