# hyperref-link-spans-a-pagebreak-looks-ugly

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

any news on 
[hyperref-link-spans-a-pagebreak-looks-ugly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54136/hyperref-link-spans-a-pagebreak-looks-ugly)?
Any way around it?
Please help, I really need it.

EDIT
Since it seems a difficult unsolved issue, what I am asking for is a quick fix, that may help for a decent output. In particular is there any easy way to ask to render \cite into the next page, instead of a split between two pages. Since I need it within a footnote, it would not look so ugly.

EDIT

normal space between words[image]
enlarged space between words (link moved to next page) [image]

Comment: Well, did you try with latest `hyperref` versions?

Comment: later than: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) restricted \write18 enabled ?

Comment: `hyperref` and `pdftex` are different things: The first is a package, the second one is a program, which transforms `hyperref` commands into a `.pdf` output

Comment: yup, I know. I have the same changelog as at http://tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/ChangeLog, whose latest change is dated 2012-11-06  6.83m. Do you know something newer?

Comment: See [my answer for "page break in the middle of a \cite"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179907/16967).

Comment: This question is rather a comment for the cited question, the means of StackExchange are bounties to get more attention to old unsolved questions. Therefore I will have to close this as duplicate.

Comment: ops I can't comment over there. @HeikoOberdiek I see your clever solution. But is there a simple one, where I just ask to render \cite in the next page (instead to split them)?

Comment: @mario: Leaving a gap on the previous page? Seems also ugly.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: it would be better than now

Comment: @mario: Example: put a `\label` before and after the `\cite`, compare the page references and put `\cite` into a `\mbox` if the page references differ.

Comment: @mario: Example in my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182769/16967) of the related [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54136/16967).

Answer (score 0):

The readme should be up-to-date so the link provide by egreg should be enough to know: http://tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/README

so:

> PostScript driver: the current implementation doesn't relly support nested links. The start positions should be remembered in a stack, but there are complications with page breaks.

It's still in devellopement. You should contact the maintener to have more information, this could be found here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

Comment: The maintainer is Heiko Oberdiek and he is on TeX.SX, so it is possible to ping him in chat, for example.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I am not the maintainer of pdfTeX.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek It seems that the problem is coming from hyperref not pdfTeX

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I did not meant `pdftex`, but `hyperref`, I referred to the link given by R. Picot. I should have been more precise ;-)

Comment: @RomainPicot: It is a missing feature at the driver level. There is not much that `hyperref` can do.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: In fact I've followed the link given by mario where the accepted answer said: "This bad behavior is a very old misfeature of hyperref that, unfortunately, hasn't yet been solved."

Comment: @RomainPicot: The TeX level does not have full access to the driver program/level.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Here, hyperref works fine for .dvi output. So I do think it is not a hyperref issue, at least not just a hyperref issue. Do you know for sure it is a pdftex issue?

Comment: @mario: The DVI format does not know links at all. It depends on the capabilities of the driver, whether and how links are supported.

Comment: @mario: Nobody, lack of volunteers. :-(

Comment: @mario: This [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179879/16967) splits up the text of a link and converts each unit into a link. The method has the advantage for a very good support of page breaks. But also this method has its limitations, see the documentation of package `soul`. Also the link is split up in pieces forming many link annotations.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I am trying, but I need a break :-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Yes, your [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179879/16967) works almost perfect. 'almost' because it spaces out words of the entire paragraph. Is it supposed to work so?

Comment: @mario: Unclear, what you are meaning. Can you make an example.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: see edit. (and thanks so much for your help. I am offline until tomorrow)

Comment: @mario: It is normal, there is not enough material to fill two lines. And the text is too long to fit on one line. (And with the URL, the text is too long for two lines.)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek:Still there? I forgot: same issue with \cite command. Clearly I need a different fix than [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179879/16967)